# How to enable Javascript to communicate with a Python 2.7 Bottle application via WebSockets?

Tags: python-2.7, websocket, bottle, gevent

**Environment**

```
Python 2.7  
bottle==0.12.9  
gevent==1.1.2  
gevent-websocket==0.9.5
greenlet==0.4.10
```

**Desired Behaviour**

On executing a Bottle route, from a `getJSON()` request of a single user on the frontend of a website, I want to utilise WebSockets to send data back to update a div in the front end of the website, which is visible to all users.

**Current Behaviour**

After implementing the steps below, I am getting Python errors from `tail -100 /var/log/apache2/error.log` which ends in:

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 8953:tid 140138351044352] [client 127.0.0.1:32820] LoopExit: ('This operation would block forever', <Hub at 0x7f746570d7d0 epoll default pending=0 ref=0 fileno=13 resolver=<gevent.resolver_thread.Resolver at 0x7f74656737d0 pool=<ThreadPool at 0x7f7465615210 0/1/10>> threadpool=<ThreadPool at 0x7f7465615210 0/1/10>>)
```

**What I've Tried**

I am following this official [brief Bottle example](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html#finally-websockets) to include WebSocket functionality in an existing Python 2.7 Bottle application.

This is the relevant Python code I have:

```
from bottle import route, post, default_app, template, view, TEMPLATE_PATH, response, request, static_file, install, redirect, abort

application=default_app()

@route('/websocket')
def handle_websocket():
    wsock = request.environ.get('wsgi.websocket')
    if not wsock:
        abort(400, 'Expected WebSocket request.')

    while True:
        try:
            message = wsock.receive()
            wsock.send("Your message was: %r" % message)
        except WebSocketError:
            break

from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from geventwebsocket import WebSocketError
from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler
server = WSGIServer(("127.0.0.1", 8080), application,
                    handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31602136/1063287), I added the following above the last section of imports:

```
from gevent import monkey, sleep
monkey.patch_all()
```

And the same error occurred after a `sudo systemctl restart apache2.service`:

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 9252:tid 140619290474240] [client 127.0.0.1:33322] LoopExit: ('This operation would block forever', <Hub at 0x7fe45f274c30 epoll default pending=0 ref=0 fileno=13 resolver=<gevent.resolver_thread.Resolver at 0x7fe45f1bfa10 pool=<ThreadPool at 0x7fe45f18a110 0/1/10>> threadpool=<ThreadPool at 0x7fe45f18a110 0/1/10>>)
```

And via virtualenv I have installed:

```
pip install gevent
pip install gevent-websocket
```

**Javascript**

WebSockets, and the related terminology, are new to me, so I am just trying to get the simple example working and then build from there.

```
$(document).on("click",".my_class, function () {
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/websocket");
ws.onopen = function() {
ws.send("Hello, world");
};
ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
alert(evt.data);
};
});
```

Comment: Are you using `mod_wsgi`? How it is configured?

Comment: I am using `mod_wsgi`.  Where would I find the config information?  It has been a while since I set it up, would it suffice to copy the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/my-site.conf` file contents into the question?